OpenIPC: remote camera control
The IP-camera has OpenIPC installed. I want to configure the camera remotely.
IP-cameras are usually controlled via a CGI. For example:
Read settings:
http://192.168.1.10/cgi-bin/hi3510/param.cgi?cmd=getimageattr
Response: var brightness="100";var hue="50"; etc.
Write brightness:
http://192.168.1.10/cgi-bin/hi3510/param.cgi?cmd=setimageattr&-brightness=100
Response: 200 OK
How to control camera remotely using OpenIPC?

SSH: cli -s .image.luminance 50 ; killall -HUP majestic
killall -HUP majestic - this is a restart, otherwise the settings are not applied.
